# How I can traverse a tree structure using closure tables in order to create a json at Eloquent models?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, transitive-closure-table

In my application I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE files (
    id bigint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    name nvarchar(255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    folder bigint NULL,
    [type] nvarchar(10) NOT NULL CHECK ([type] IN ('FILE', 'FOLDER')) DEFAULT 'FOLDER',
    CONSTRAINT PK__3213E83FDB19A582 PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT folder_fk FOREIGN KEY (folder) REFERENCES files(id),
);

create table files_closure (
    ancestor bigint NOT NULL,
    decedant bigint NOT NULL,
    "depth" int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT files_closure_pk PRIMARY KEY (ancestor,decedant),
    CONSTRAINT files_closure_ancestor_fk FOREIGN KEY (ancestor) REFERENCES files(id),
    CONSTRAINT files_closure_decedant_fk FOREIGN KEY (decedant) REFERENCES files(id),
);
```

And each table has its own Model as well:

Files

```
class Files extends Model
{
  protected $table='files';
  public $timestamps = false;
  
  public function parentFolder():HasOne
  {
     return $this->hasOne(self::class,'id','folder');
  }

  public function files(): HasMany
  {
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'folder');
  }
}
```

And for the closure table:

```
class FilesClosure extends Model
{
  protected $table='files_closure';
  public $timestamps = false;
  
  public function ancestor():HasOne
  {
     return $this->hasOne(Files::class,'ancestor','id');
  }

  
  public function decedant():HasOne
  {
     return $this->hasOne(Files::class,'ancestor','id');
  }
}
```

And I want to create a json structure as fast as possible (in the least ammout of execution time without causing database overhead):

```
{
  files: [
      {
        name:"My Music",
        type: "FOLDER",
        files: [
           {
             name: "Halford",
             type: "FOLDER",
             files: [
               {
                 name: "Locked-and-loaded.mp3",
                 type: "FILE"
               },
               {
                 name: "Another Song.mp3",
                 type: "FILE"
               }
             ]
           }
        ]
      }
  ]
}
```

If I avoided using the closure table I could retrieve the data as:

```
$json = Files::with('parentFolder','files')->whereNull('folder')->get()->toJson();
```

But that results having multiple queries and have slow response time especially on large datasets. Therefore I want to use the closure table but I am stuck on how I can do this.

Comment: If you define class as `File` you don't need `$table = 'files'`. Laravel will do that automagically for you

Comment: Personal Preference.

Answer (score 0):

Check below where I modified the Laravel `Files` model to efficiently handle hierarchical data using a closure table. The approach involves a single query that joins the `files` table with the `files_closure` table to retrieve the hierarchical data, respecting the folder-file structure. This data is then processed in PHP to construct a tree-like structure. A static method `getHierarchicalData` in the `Files` model fetches the data and another set of methods `buildTree` and `buildBranch` are used to organize this data into a nested tree format, reflecting the folder-file hierarchy. This method minimizes the number of database queries, especially beneficial for large datasets, and the final tree structure is converted into a JSON format, suitable for the required output.

```
class Files extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'files';
    public $timestamps = false;

    // New method to retrieve hierarchical data
    public static function getHierarchicalData()
    {
        // Get hierarchical data
        $data = DB::table('files as f')
            ->join('files_closure as fc', 'f.id', '=', 'fc.decedant')
            ->select('f.*', 'fc.ancestor', 'fc.depth')
            ->orderBy('fc.ancestor')
            ->orderBy('fc.depth')
            ->get();

        return self::buildTree($data);
    }

    protected static function buildTree($data)
    {
        $items = [];
        foreach ($data as $item) {
            $items[$item->ancestor][] = $item;
        }

        $tree = self::buildBranch($items, null);
        return $tree;
    }

    protected static function buildBranch(&$items, $parentId)
    {
        $branch = [];
        foreach ($items[$parentId] as $item) {
            if (isset($items[$item->id])) {
                $item->files = self::buildBranch($items, $item->id);
            } else {
                $item->files = [];
            }
            $branch[] = $item;
        }
        return $branch;
    }
}
```

In the controller, you call:

```
$json = json_encode(Files::getHierarchicalData());
```

Hydrate some models using the query

```
public static function getHierarchicalData()
{
    // Get hierarchical data
    $data = DB::table('files as f')
        ->join('files_closure as fc', 'f.id', '=', 'fc.decedant')
        ->select('f.*', 'fc.ancestor', 'fc.depth')
        ->orderBy('fc.ancestor')
        ->orderBy('fc.depth')
        ->get();

    // Hydrate Files models from the raw data
    $models = Files::hydrate($data->toArray());

    return self::buildTree($models);
}
```

Comment: I wonder if using a stack could make `buildBranch` more efficient.

Comment: Also could I hydrate some models using the query as well?

Comment: Using a stack could potentially make the process more efficient, especially in terms of readability and managing the function's call stack. In the real-world performance gain might be minimal unless you're dealing with a very large and deeply nested hierarchy. About hydrating models from the query: yes, you can hydrate Laravel models directly from a query result. This is useful as it allows you to interact with the resulting objects using the full range of Eloquent features. I updated the answer on how you can modify your getHierarchicalData method to hydrate Files models.

Comment: What happens if parent_id is not null? I mean the `$tree = self::buildBranch($items, null);` will not work with `$parentId` as null  because in my case the ancestor is not null.